# Range highlighting (not selecting) in Rickshaw D3.js charts

Tags: d3.js, rickshaw

I have a problem with finding a way to highlight a specific range and possibly label it at the top in the Rickshaw charts as on this example

[image]

Is there a way of achieving such a highlight in Rickshaw? It could be very useful for annotating a period rather than point in time.

Do you have any ideas how can I achieve that?

Comment: You could add a rectangle covering the region you want to highlight manually.

Comment: How should I know the x and y of the point it should start at?

Comment: Hmm, it looks like you can't get access to the scales that rickshaw uses unfortunately, so this won't work. If start/end correspond to a specific data point though, you could get the DOM element that corresponds to it though and use its coordinates.

Comment: You can use graph.x(value) to get the position for any date. This will return the left offset from the graph 0 point.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I am comparing Rickshaw v/s Dygraph and dygraph seems to have a highlight feature that Rickshaw doesn't explicitly. Reference - http://dygraphs.com/gallery/#g/highlighted-region